# Can we add remove namespace reference (usings) dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I need to invoke WCF service 1 or WCF service 2, based on certain condition evaluated at runtime. Both the services are similar but hosted on different servers.

I have added two service references, NS1 and NS2 pointing to different urls. Current code already uses NS1. Considering this NS1 implementation has already been done at many places. What would be best way to refactor the code, to select dynamically which service has to be invoked ?

Comment: Your question probably needs some details on how you're invoking the service methods, but why couldn't you just have the two different endpoints defined in your config and then use the appropriate one based on your situation?

Comment: Are the services just *similar* or *exactly the same*?

Comment: Is NS2 a backup or load balance to NS1 or do they do different tasks?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth services are similar not same, I mean they are be different versions so may contain slightly different data contract.

Comment: Is your condition evaluated once at startup or could it change throughout the lifetime of the process?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth In case of evaluating at startup we could have used web.config key. It will change thourgh out the life time of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is considered a bad practice to program directly against the proxy generated by the svcutil.exe.

The best way is to wrap it in a class of your own and reference this class each time you require the service. This will also allow you to implement more advanced business logic such as routing (in your case) and other cross cutting concerns. 
For example: you can now abstract from the application the strategy you are using to connect to the service, i.e. Service reference or ChannelFactory. You can easily share the service between different assemblies without ambiguity.

You are saying that you have much code written directly against NS1. Grind your teeth and wrap it. It is a lot of dirty work but the risk is very low.

Having said the above, I wonder about the requirement itself, where a service calls another instance of itself on another server (if I got you right). This smells funny, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Vitaliy Sorry if I sounded ambigous, Service is not going to call another instance of iself.. rather client has to decide at runtime which version of the service has to be invoked..

Comment: I see. First of all, my answer stands. Regardless,
what were the changes from the older version to the new one? (Maybe we should be talking about backward compatibility).